# Adding hyperlink button in a text block programatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, hyperlink

How can i add a hyperlink button inside a text block through `c#` at the end of the text.
In `XAML` part i have a text block

```
<TextBlock  Name="PresenterDescription" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Foreground="White" MinHeight="200" FontSize="16"/>
```

in .cs file i am doing this..

```
Run run1 = new Run();
run1.Text = "some text";
HyperlinkButton hyperlinkButton = new HyperlinkButton()
{
    Content = " read more..",
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    NavigateUri = new Uri("http://somelink.com", UriKind.Absolute)
};
PresenterDescription.Inlines.Add(run1);
```

But how can i add the hyperlink button to this text block ?, As i can not add it as inline..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `XAML` part i did the following

```
<RichTextBox  Name="PresenterDescription"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16">
            <Paragraph >
                       <Hyperlink Click="readMoreclick">
                            <Underline Foreground="White">read more..</Underline>
                      </Hyperlink>
             </Paragraph>
 </RichTextBox>
```

And in `c#` part the text to be displayed before the link as..

```
PresenterDescription.Selection.Text = "Text to be displayed";
```

And finally the event handler for link click..

```
  private void readMoreclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
            WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
            webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("www.example.com", UriKind.Absolute);
            webBrowserTask.Show();
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add HyperlinkButton instead you can add HyperLink to TextBlock, Or you can use RichTextBlock like this

```
     <RichTextBlock x:Name="textblock"/>

 Run run1 = new Run();
run1.Text = "some text";
HyperlinkButton hyperlinkButton = new HyperlinkButton()
{
    Content = " read more..",
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    NavigateUri = new Uri("http://somelink.com", UriKind.Absolute)
};
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
InlineUIContainer inline = new InlineUIContainer();
inline.Child = hyperlinkButton;
para.Inlines.Add(run1);
para.Inlines.Add(inline);
textblock.Blocks.Add(para);
```